# How to verify signatures of a PE in my driver?

Tags: c++, api, kernel, driver, signature

I am writing a driver and I need to check the signature of a PE file in it. I know how to do it in user mode and it works fine according to http://forum.sysinternals.com/topic19247.html[^] but now I need to do the same in my driver, I can not use the headers like "wintrust.h" in my driver so I am clueless. Any suggestions on how to verify PE signatures in kernel mode?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Self-checking won't give you anything, unfortunately - the one that tampers the driver would remove the check as well. For educational needs, however, this is an interesting but challenging task.

You would need to implement Authenticode validation yourself. Authenticode is based on PKCS#7/CMS and X.509 certificates. You would need to re-implement all that stuff in kernel mode.

While implementing RSA is trivial, ASN.1 parser and PKCS7 format handling are much more complicated. You might want to find some existing C code that can be adapted for kernel mode. For example, you can check [cryptlib](http://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~pgut001/cryptlib/). Cryptlib supports CMS (and this is what you need) and is heavily cross-platform, so you should not have problems adapting it for kernel mode.

Comment: Thank you for your response. This seems very complicated. I guess it would be easier if I detect a PE in my driver and then pass the PE file path to my user mode application...

Comment: This is interesting, I am trying to do something similar. However I do not understand how Authenticode can help you in this scenario ....

Comment: @NorbertBoros Authenticode is the standard used to sign PE files. So the question is not whether it "helps" but how you would use it in the kernel mode. Calling back the user-mode application like the OP considered in the previous comment adds nothing to security - the attacker would just replace the user-mode code with the fake one (or patch that code).

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'AlliedBits Yeah I understand, I am looking for a similar solution. Basically I need to create some sort of way to detect inside kernel other drivers based on signature/dump ( if that makes sense )... so far no luck. Unless I start to develop my own antivirus...lol